# React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by Dashboard

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useJwt } from "react-jwt";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import {useNavigate} from "react-router-dom"

import { setUserData, clearUserData } from "./features/auth/authSlice";
import { getAccount } from "./features/user/dataSlice";

import Header from "./components/Header";
import Announcement from "./components/Announcement";
import Sidebar from "./components/Sidebar";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import Loader from "./components/Loader";

import Home from "./pages/HomePage";
import FundAccount from "./pages/FundAccount";
import Withdraw from "./pages/Withdraw";
import BuyData from "./pages/BuyData";
import BuyAirtime from "./pages/BuyAirtime";
import PayCableTv from "./pages/PayCableTv";
import PayElectricity from "./pages/PayElectricity";
import Profile from "./pages/Profile";
import Setting from "./pages/Setting";
import Transactions from "./pages/Transactions";

const BASE_URL =
  import.meta.env.VITE_MODE === "DEV"
    ? import.meta.env.VITE_BASE_URL_TEST
    : import.meta.env.VITE_BASE_URL_LIVE;

function Dashboard({currentPage, setCurrentPage}) {
  const [isMenuOpen, setIsMenuOpen] = useState(false);
  const [showMenu, setShowMenu] = useState(false);
  
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
  const [isTransActive, setIsTransActive] = useState(false);
  const [urlState, setUrlState] = useState("#dashboard")

  const navigate = useNavigate()

  const toggleMenu = () => setIsMenuOpen((prevState) => !prevState);

  const closeAllMenu = () => {
    showMenu === true ? setShowMenu(false) : null;
    if (active) {
      setActive(false);
    }
    if (isTransActive) {
      setIsTransActive(false);
    }
  };

  const handleLogout = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem("user");
    localStorage.removeItem("account");
    dispatch(clearUserData());
    window.location = `${BASE_URL}/users/logout`;
  };

  
  const showPage = (pageTitle) => {
    const url = window.location.pathname;
    let newState = url;

    const fragments = [
      "#dashboard",
      "#fund-account",
      "#withdraw",
      "#transactions",
      "#buy-data",
      "#buy-airtime",
      "#pay-electricity-bill",
      "#pay-cable-tv",
      "#profile",
      "#setting",
    ];

    // const currentFragment = window.location.href.split("#")[1]

    // console.log(currentFragment)
    // console.log(pageTitle);
    // console.log(url);

    switch (pageTitle) {
      case "Home":
        newState += "#dashboard";
        //window.history.replaceState(null, "", newState);
        
        return (
          <Home
            setCurrentPage={setCurrentPage}
            setIsLoading={setIsLoading}
            isTransActive={isTransActive}
            setIsTransActive={setIsTransActive}
          />
        );
      case "Fund Account":
        newState += "#fund-account";
        
        // window.history.replaceState(null, "", newState);
        return <FundAccount setIsLoading={setIsLoading} />;
      case "Withdraw":
        newState += "#withdraw";
        
        // window.history.replaceState(null, "", newState);
        return <Withdraw setIsLoading={setIsLoading} />;
      case "Transactions":
        newState += "#transactions";
        
        // window.history.replaceState(null, "", newState);
        return <Transactions setIsLoading={setIsLoading} />;
      case "Buy Data":
        newState += "#buy-data";
        
        // window.history.replaceState(null, "", newState);
        return <BuyData setIsLoading={setIsLoading} />;
      case "Buy Airtime":
        newState += "#buy-airtime";
        
        // window.history.replaceState(null, "", newState);
        return <BuyAirtime setIsLoading={setIsLoading} />;
      case "Pay Electricity Bill":
        newState += "#pay-electricity";
        
        // window.history.replaceState(null, "", newState);
        return <PayElectricity setIsLoading={setIsLoading} />;
      case "Pay Cable Tv":
        newState += "#pay-cable-tv";
        
        // window.history.replaceState(null, "", newState);
        return <PayCableTv setIsLoading={setIsLoading} />;
      case "Profile":
        newState += "#profile";
        
        // window.history.replaceState(null, "", newState);
        return <Profile setIsLoading={setIsLoading} />;
      case "Setting":
        newState += "#setting";
        
        // window.history.replaceState(null, "", newState);
        return <Setting setIsLoading={setIsLoading} />;
      default:
        newState += "#dashboard";
        
        // window.history.replaceState(null, "", newState);
        return <Home setIsLoading={setIsLoading} />;
    }
  };

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
  const { isDataLoading } = useSelector((state) => state.data);
  const { isPurchaseLoading } = useSelector((state) => state.purchase);

  const account = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("account"));

  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  const token = urlParams.get("token");
  const getToken = token && useJwt(token);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (token && getToken && !getToken?.isExpired && !user) {
      localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(getToken.decodedToken));
      dispatch(setUserData(getToken.decodedToken));
    }
  }, [getToken?.decodedToken, dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) dispatch(getAccount(user.id));
  }, [user, dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const uri = new URL(`${window.location.protocol}//${window.location.host}`)
  }, [])
  

  return (
    <>
      {isDataLoading && <Loader />}
      {isLoading && <Loader />}
      {isPurchaseLoading && <Loader />}
      <div
        className={`layout-wrapper layout-content-navbar ${
          isMenuOpen ? "layout-menu-expanded" : ""
        }`}
        onClick={(e) => closeAllMenu(e)}
      >
        <div className="layout-container">
          <Sidebar
            currentPage={currentPage}
            setCurrentPage={setCurrentPage}
            setIsMenuOpen={setIsMenuOpen}
            handleLogout={handleLogout}
          />
          {/* <!-- Layout container --> */}
          <div className="layout-page">
            <Navbar
              isMenuOpen={isMenuOpen}
              setIsMenuOpen={setIsMenuOpen}
              handleClick={toggleMenu}
              setCurrentPage={setCurrentPage}
              showMenu={showMenu}
              setShowMenu={setShowMenu}
              handleLogout={handleLogout}
            />
            {/* <!-- Content wrapper --> */}
            <div className="content-wrapper">
              {/* <!-- Content --> */}
              <div className="container-xxl flex-grow-1 container-p-y">
                {currentPage === "Profile" ||
                currentPage === "Setting" ||
                currentPage === "Transactions" ? (
                  ""
                ) : (
                  <div className="row">
                    <Header
                      account={account}
                      setCurrentPage={setCurrentPage}
                      active={active}
                      setActive={setActive}
                    />
                    <Announcement />
                  </div>
                )}

                {showPage(currentPage)}
              </div>
              <footer className="content-footer footer bg-footer-theme">
                <div className="container-xxl d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between py-2 flex-md-row flex-column">
                  
                </div>
              </footer>
              <div className="content-backdrop fade"></div>
            </div>
            {/* <!-- Content wrapper --> */}
          </div>
          {/* <!-- / Layout page --> */}
        </div>

        {/* <!-- Overlay --> */}
        <div
          className="layout-overlay layout-menu-toggle"
          onClick={() => setIsMenuOpen(false)}
        ></div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Dashboard;
```

I am trying to create a react application which vite where I send data from a backend with a different url (http://localhost:3500). I make a redirect from the backend to the vite frontend and send the data through a query param called token then I use the useJWT to decode the token and make I dispatch, my problem is that I want to change the page url from localhost:5173?token=... to localhost:5173#dashboard but when I use the window.location.pushState(null, "", newState) or replaceState(null, "", newState), I get the error below

Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by Dashboard. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed. For more information, read the Rules of Hooks: https://reactjs.org/link/rules-of-hooks

### Previous render            Next render

1. useContext                 useContext
2. useContext                 useContext
3. useRef                     useRef
4. useCallback                useCallback
5. useRef                     useRef
6. useMemo                    useMemo
7. useSyncExternalStore       useSyncExternalStore
8. useEffect                  useEffect
9. useDebugValue              useDebugValue
10. useDebugValue             useDebugValue
11. useContext                useContext
12. useRef                    useRef
13. useCallback               useCallback
14. useRef                    useRef
15. useMemo                   useMemo
16. useSyncExternalStore      useSyncExternalStore
17. useEffect                 useEffect
18. useDebugValue             useDebugValue
19. useDebugValue             useDebugValue
20. useContext                useContext
21. useRef                    useRef
22. useCallback               useCallback
23. useRef                    useRef
24. useMemo                   useMemo
25. useSyncExternalStore      useSyncExternalStore
26. useEffect                 useEffect
27. useDebugValue             useDebugValue
28. useDebugValue             useDebugValue
29. useState                  useEffect
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    at Dashboard (http://localhost:5173/src/Dashboard.jsx?t=1692559813161:41:20)
    at App
    at Provider (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-redux.js?v=cb62aef7:1507:3)

if there is anyone who understands hooks or have a better way I can send data from  a different url to this vite url without having to cause this problem should please help me out with the solution. Thanks

I tried moving the useEffect way above all my code, but it still tells me about the problem and I also found out that the error occurs whenever there is a useEffect and window.history.pushState in One Component
And I a thinking of changing the whole code to use react-router-dom

Comment: can you share the entire `Dashboard` component?

Comment: I just edited the code to contain the entire dashboard code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is with this line:

```
const getToken = token && useJwt(token)
```

there is a conditional usage of a hook (the hook is executed only when `token` is thruthy)

Instead, try passing `token` into `useJwt` in all cases, e.g.:

```
const getToken = useJwt(token)
```

or, if you need to handle undefined tokens, you could do something like this.

```
const getToken = useJwt(token || '')
```

Comment: @AlexanderUkwueze consider accepting the answer then for future readers

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in

> Dashboard

component.

Basically, you have some conditional hooks (etc: hooks inside if statements) and this is bad, at least for react.

Comment: Do you mean I shouldn't use the dispatch() inside an if statement?

Comment: I just found out that the `useJwt()`  hook is kinda causing the problems
When I use the useEffect hook with that particular hook, it throws the problem even if I don't add any conditions inside the useEffect, but when I comment the useJwt out my code works fine, do u know what I can do in this case @mohamed-daw

Comment: You should not put a hook inside another
useEffect runs when one of its triggers change (This is kind of conditional)

Comment: Rethink about the code logic